# MongoDB dot notation when updating

Tags: mongodb

**Answer:** It was only a bug of 1.4.4. Upgrade to 2.0 has solved the problem.

I have the following object in Mongo:

```
{
  _id: "foo",
  bar: "baz",
  list: {
    42: { some: "prop" }
  }
}
```

I want to add in the "list" a key 43, so I'm doing the following:

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: "foo"
}, {
  $set: {
    "list.43": { some: "other prop" }
  }
})
```

Everything is fine, but the 43 with new subobject became the only key in list property. Why? Why has 42 gone?

Expected result:

```
{
  _id: "foo",
  bar: "baz",
  list: {
    42: { some: "prop" },
    43: { some: "other prop" }
  }
}
```

Real result:

```
{
  _id: "foo",
  bar: "baz",
  list: {
    43: { some: "other prop" }
  }
}
```

**Update:** In fact, the question is how to add a key into a nested object in one atomic call?

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you running? Your example, works as [you] expected on 1.8x shell, resulting in list as a two node object. Any chance you have a typo in the update or are retrieving the wrong object?

Comment: Thanks, it was a bug of v.1.4.4

Answer (score 0):

That should work. Maybe you deleted it previously with a wrong update?

Try it again.